# PyCharm error while running Markovify project

Tags: python, pycharm, markov

I just recently downloaded the [Markovify](https://github.com/jsvine/markovify) project and I can't seem to figure out how to make it work. I've installed the markovify package, and have the project settings below:

[Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4hT7.png)

When I run the code, I get the following error:

[Project Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB41h.png)

Any suggestion on how I could fix this issue?

Thank you!

```
import markovify

# Get raw text as string.
with open("/Users/dariush/PycharmProjects/Markov/Markovify/test/texts/senate-bills.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()

# Build the model.
text_model = markovify.Text(text)

# Print five randomly-generated sentences
for i in range(5):
    print(text_model.make_sentence())

# Print three randomly-generated sentences of no more than 280 characters
for i in range(3):
    print(text_model.make_short_sentence(280))
```

Comment: Anyone?! :-D...

Comment: Try to rename the file, since you are trying to import it instead of expected one by doing `import markovify`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! What should I rename the file to?

Comment: It is up to you, just don't duplicate already existing names